# JavaScript, objects and concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, socket.io

I have a relatively simple project with very little code that is giving me headaches as I don't know what is causing the problem. The idea is similar to http://tweetping.net/, but it is not showing real-time tweets, but real-time connections of users to a service.

The service uses nodejs as a UPD listener and socket.io to communicate with the web browser. Socket.io then listens to messages and when it receives one it draws a marker on a Google map.

This is the entire JavaScript on the page:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    var map = false;
    var markers = {};
    var markerTimeouts = {};

    $(window).load(function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 16),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },              
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    });

    function createMarker(name, lng, lat) {
        var circle = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                map: map,
                icon: "/img/marker_red.png?v=2",
                title: name
        });

        markers[name] = circle;

        setTimeout(function() { destroyMarker(name); }, 3000);
    }

    function destroyMarker(name) {
        markers[name].setMap(null);
        delete markers[name];
    }

    socket.on('message', function(data){
        if (!map) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            createMarker(data.name, data.lon, data.lat);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

The problem happens when there are a lot of concurrent messages (100/s) coming from socket.io. The markers get created just fine via the createMarker method, but when I try removing them 3 seconds later (via setTimeout) the object `markers[name]` is undefined.

I would make a fiddle.js example, but it's impossible to recreate the many concurrent socket.io messages.

Did anybody have a situation where javascript was not able to push something to an object via the `object[key] = something;` syntax? Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**: Note to self: always check if you already have this key in the markers object. Adding the following code solved the issue.

```
if (name in markers) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting same name twice?

Comment: this wont fix your issue but you should use `setTimeout(destroyMarker.bind(this, name), 3000);` I also wonder if `setMap` is running asynchronously, and the delete runs before that function can finish? just a thought.

Comment: Good thinking guys! I didn't think I would get a makrer with the same name twice, but actually adding `if (name in markers) { return; }` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting the same name twice (or more) in 3 seconds.

1. markers[name] is set from first message
2. markers[name] is overwritten from second message
3. markers[name] is deleted (after timer from first message)
4. Timer from second message is over but markers[name] is already deleted.